# TLE9879 BLDC shield won't communicate

Tags: motor, shields, arduino-leonardo

I just got the [TLE9879 BLDC shield](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/bldc_shield_tle9879/), which I connected to an Arduino Leonardo. Compiling the example sketch (bldc_shield_blinky_test) went fine, however, upon flashing it to the board the LED on the shield doesn't change the color (it stays white) and the following line is repeatedly printed to the Serial console:

> WARNING: Board[1]; Command[901]; Answer[0]

I have initially tried the shield in its out of the box state. I have since then flashed it with the HALL version of the shield software, using the project included in the SW distribution that comes with the shield. In both cases, the shield behaved as described above when connected to the Arduino.

Does anybody know what this warning message is about?

Comment: @jsotola It behaved exactly the same before and after flashing. I assume it came pre-flashed.

Comment: what happens if you run the sketch without the BLDC shield connected to the arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use TLE9879, but I could guess of why it doesn't work as expected.

For ATMega328p-based Arduino boards (i.e. Uno, Nano and Pro Mini), it has pin 11, 12 and 13 as SPI’s MOSI, MISO and SCLK signals, but at the same time these signals are also available on those board’s In-Circuit Serial Programming (ICSP) header pin 4, 1 and 3, except for Pro Mini which does not have a dedicated ICSP header.

This however is not the case for Arduino Leonardo and Arduino Micro which are based on ATMega32U4, for those boards, the SPI is only available on ICSP header. This is one of the reasons that some of the Arduino shields designed for Arduino Uno does not work with Arduino Leonardo when SPI communication is involved.

Based on the information of TLE9879, the SPI port is connected to pin 11-13 so it is designed to work with Arduino Uno but will not work for Arduino Leonardo.